# Does Selenium ChromeDriver currently have support for handling pop-up windows?

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

I have a pop-up window that I have to handle after clicking a button on the Chrome browser.
As soon as the popup is launched programmatically, any further action by the driver object results in this exception:

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: No response from server for url

Also there is no change in number of windowhandles list (`driver.WindowHandles`) after the pop-up window is launched. Please don't confuse this with switching windows in tabs.

Does Selenium ChromeDriver currently have support for handling pop-up windows?

Comment: Is it a standard JS alert? Does `driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();` do much?

Comment: No,it is a separate chrome window.Not an alert window.

Answer (score 1):

Treating pop-up window is the same as treating number of windows.
Try to do:

```
driver().switchTo().window((String)driver.getWindowHandles().toArray()[index]);
```

Where index is the index of the new window (can be passed as an argument in appropriate switch-window function).

Later, you can implement it in more clean way such as:

*In our case the webdriver is warped in WebDriverProxy object.

```
    public static void switchFocusToWindowNumber(int index, WebDriverProxy webDriverProxy) {
    try {
        webDriverProxy.getWebDriver().switchTo().window((String) webDriverProxy.getWebDriver().getWindowHandles().toArray()[index]);
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Number of open windows is: "
                + getNumberofWindows(webDriverProxy) + " Trying to close window number: " + index + "\n Exception: " + e);
    }    catch (NoSuchWindowException e) {
        throw new NoSuchWindowException ("NoSuchWindowException: Number of windows is: " + getNumberofWindows(webDriverProxy) +
                " Trying to close window number: " + index + "\n Exception: " + e);
    }

}
```